# How to delete rows in Excel based on the date in minutes?

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula

I have a large dataset in Excel with some repeated data. I am trying to write a macro that looks at the date and deletes the entire row if the measurement was not taken at 51 minutes. For example, sample 22 was taken at 21:16 so that row would be deleted from the dataset.

My existing code:

```
Sub Delete_Extra_Data()
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = ":51" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image: d]

Comment: It's really helpful to include any code you may have already tried even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Just edited my post I think my problem is telling excel to ignore all the text except for the :51 at the end, nothing happens when I run the macro since no cells exaclty equal :51.

Comment: Times (and dates) are just numbers in Excel. You could use the MINUTE formula I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should work. Your code suggests you want to delete if 51 but your description says the opposite so adjust to suit.

```
Sub Delete_Extra_Data()

Dim Last As Long, i As Long

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If Minute(Cells(i, "B")) <> 51 Then 'or =51
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```